# Selecting and Rearranging HTML Elements with Python

Tags: python, html

How can the following unstructured table element can be structured, without using any library.

```
<table>
 <tfoot>
    <tr><td>Sum</td><td>$180</td></tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>January</td><td>$100</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Desired table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>January</td><td>$100</td></tr>
  </tbody>
   <tfoot>
    <tr><td>Sum</td><td>$180</td></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

It is important to maintain the order of attributes of html elements. I have tried using Beautifulsoup. It changes the order. Please suggest any pythonic way of solving this problem, which doesn't require using beautifulsoup or lxml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex via `re`:

```
import re
s = """
<table>
  <tfoot>
    <tr><td>Sum</td><td>$180</td></tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>January</td><td>$100</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
"""
new_s = re.sub('\<tfoot\>[\w\W]+\</tfoot\>|\<tbody\>[\w\W]+\</tbody\>', '{}', s).format(*re.findall('\<tfoot\>[\w\W]+\</tfoot\>|\<tbody\>[\w\W]+\</tbody\>', s)[::-1])
```

Output:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr><td>January</td><td>$100</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
     <tr><td>Sum</td><td>$180</td></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ajax1234 for your response. Is it possible to play the tfoot below tbody?